# SciPy signal.tukey Module Error

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, signal-processing

I am getting an error when I run the code below in Pycharm. When I run the same code in terminal, it works fine! Anyone know what's going on? Is this a bug?

```
from scipy import signal
window = signal.tukey(51)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your PyCharm version might not be the same as your default Python install. Check to see which version they are by doing; `import sys; print(sys.version, sys.executable)`, which will print the full path and version of the current Python interpreter. If the executables are different, it's likely you have different SciPy versions in each.

Comment: I ensured they were on the same version, and it didn't help.

Comment: are the scipy versions the same? The `signal.tukey` addition is a brand new feature to the SciPy stack. Any version before 0.16.1, such as the default install on Ubuntu (0.14.1), will not have the Tukey function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I installed Anaconda, and followed the 'PyCharm' section of [this](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration) guide. It fixed everything for me.